# WebSQL create view

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, view, web-sql

Is it possible to use views with WebSQL? I assume it is because it is basically sqlite which definitely allows it, but I might as well be wrong. I am trying to create a view in my local sqlite database but it fails no matter what I do. Here are some of the things I've tried so far;

```
create view my_view as select id, name from my_table where active = 1;
--fails: could not prepare statement (1 no such table: main.my_table)
```

Why does it search for table 'my_table' in the 'main' database? I was not even aware of the 'main' database. I assume it is some system database that is there by default. The database that I open is labeled 'my_database'. All the other sql statements seem to respect that. The 'create view' is the only one that looks like it operates outside of the opened database.

```
create view my_view as select id, name from my_database.my_table where active = 1;
--fails: could not prepare statement (1 view my_view cannot reference objects in database my_database)
```

This is what specifically makes me believe that the 'create view' statement operates outside of the opened database.

```
create view my_database.my_view as select id, name from my_database.my_table where active = 1;
--fails: could not prepare statement (1 unknown database my_database)
```

This one confuses me the most. How can there be that the 'my_database' database is unknown? I can assure you that I am using this database for quite a bunch of other statements such as select, insert, update, delete and all of them work perfectly fine. It is only for the 'create view' that this database is unknown.

```
create view my_database.my_view as select id, name from my_table where active = 1;
--fails: could not prepare statement (1 unknown database my_database)
```

I even tried to run these one at a time before the 'create view':

```
attach 'my_database.db' as my_database;
--fails: could not prepare statement (23 not authorized)

attach 'my_database.sqlite' as my_database;
--fails: could not prepare statement (23 not authorized)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The default database (the database you opened) is always called `main`.

You get the error "no such table: main.my_table" because your database does not contain a table called `my_table`.

Comment: right, thanks for the answer. any idea about why it searches the table inside the 'main' database? i am not doing anything with the main database. i would expect it to look inside the database that i opened with openDatabase()